# A software to resize, add a frame, custom logo and exif info on photos (mac)

Tags: osx, metadata, exif

I do locations scouting for advertisement and movies.

After a day taking photos I have to resize them, apply a frame with the bottom part of the pic heigh enough to write there the file's name, iso, f number etc and a logo company to the bottom right.

In sort,looks like a polaroid photo paper with exif info and a logo on bottom part.

I'm using an old script (Marco Exif from canonistas' forum) that does all this things but it must executed from photoshop and it is sooo slow processing the whole photos.

Do you know a software to get this resaults? I use mac.
Thanks and I'm sorry my English.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using ImageMagick as it can convert and watermark your photos as a batch from the command line. Adding the frame and filter should be possible as well although I'm not sure how difficult it would be.

Comment: Thank you Jay. But it seems to be I'm gonna need some code knowledge to play with it.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend taking a look at [BatchPhoto](https://www.batchphoto.com/). 
It's compatible with both Mac and Windows and does pretty much everything you asked for. You can resize your images, add a border, your logo and the metadata desired, all in bulk. I recommend it because it's quite easy to use and can process multiple images pretty fast.